# Location Directive giving 403 Nginx Coonfiguration

Tags: nginx

I have the below Nginx configurations that are working fine:

```
      location / {
                root /var/www/html;
                index   index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        }
```

However, I am getting a **403 forbidden error** when I just add **/site** to the URL location configuration like below

```
        location /site {
                root /var/www/html;
                index   index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        }
```

How can I resolve this in Nginx running on ubuntu 2204?

I tried **/site/** still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you check `/var/www/html/site` permissions?

Comment: yes it was permission now its not able to load static giving 404 but using first configurations everything works even the static files.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why can't you use the first configuration? Are you trying to move your application to a different URL? You cannot do that by just changing a `location` directive. Look at the access log and error log for more information.